# Can a ReactContext with 2 instances be created and used in 2 different React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I Have created a context and have Default values say

```
{ isopen = true, searchValue = 'abc'}
```

Now i want to use this context with in 2 different components with different values.

Say componentA can have React context value

```
{ isopen = true, searchValue = 'xyz'}
```

Say componentB can have React context value

```
{ isopen = true, searchValue = 'uvw'}
```

without both interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it currently (`v17`) out of the box, but there are common workarounds.

You can have either a single object to separate the provider's value for each component, or you can have separate providers.

It doesn't matter which you choose (depends on your use-case), I recommend having separate providers (readability).

Full example:

```
const InputContext = React.createContext();
const InputContext2 = React.createContext();

const Consumer = () => {
  const { value } = React.useContext(InputContext);
  return <>{value}</>;
};

const Consumer2 = () => {
  const { value2: value } = React.useContext(InputContext);
  return <>{value}</>;
};

const Consumer3 = () => {
  const { value } = React.useContext(InputContext2);
  return <>{value}</>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <InputContext.Provider value={{ value: "xyz", value2: "uvw" }}>
        <h2>
          Consumer1: <Consumer />
        </h2>
        <h2>
          Consumer2: <Consumer2 />
        </h2>
      </InputContext.Provider>
      <hr />
      <InputContext.Provider value={{ value: "xyz" }}>
        <InputContext2.Provider value={{ value: "uvw" }}>
          <h2>
            Consumer1: <Consumer />
          </h2>
          <h2>
            Consumer3: <Consumer3 />
          </h2>
        </InputContext2.Provider>
      </InputContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Value Diff Context]